# Determining visible center of SVG as rotation origin while panning and zooming

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, matrix-transform, svg-transforms

I'm developing an SVG viewer, using [svg-pan-zoom library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-pan-zoom) to pan and zoom the SVG.

**What I want**
What I want in the end is to be able to pan/zoom to a specific point in the SVG and be able to rotate from that point (and be able to repeat this process).
The red circle (when clicking or panning) is just a visual debugging tool

- [1. codepen example with click point centering & rotation origin](https://codepen.io/tmakaku/pen/RwdbMjx)
- [2. codepen example with drag/zoom centering & rotation origin](https://codepen.io/tmakaku/pen/BabBPJO)

SVG structure:

```
<svg id="svgElement" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <g id="svg-pan-zoom-container"> <!-- SVG-pan zoom translations are applied to this group -->
    <g id="group" transform="rotate(60 250 250)">
      <rect x="225" y="225" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Problem**

Updating the rotation origin results in the SVG jumping.
I tried compensating by panning to the coordinates after updating the origin.
I've tried multiple ways of determining the pan coordinates.
Updating the transform attribute while panning works fine when rotation is 0, but for ex. when rotation is 180 dragging results in the SVG moving in the opposite direction.

In the first example (with the click point as center and origin) seems to work, so I'm kind of lost why it won't work with panning.

**Questions**

- Would another zooming/panning approach work better? I've considered implementing my own solution.
- Is the a better approach to always rotating from the visual center?
- Am i stupid? :(

Comment: With the standardization in HTML5, integrating SVG (M$ kills VLC), CSS3 recovers the animation and transformation operations of SVG to make them applicable to both HTML and SVG elements. Support for its operations in direct SVG is no longer guaranteed. Use CSS3 to do your animations/transformation.

Comment: @MisterJojo I'm not sure i follow.
Are you suggestion to use CSS3 for all my transformations?

The problem is that i'm doing work in an existing project with transformations like these that i can't easily replace, and this seems to be more of an mathematical problem than anything else.

Comment: I was faced with this problem myself, and had to rewrite my SVG animations in CSS. Fortunately, CSS3 syntaxes remain in the same logic. otherwise you can also use the GSAP library...

Comment: I was considering trying GSAP, but i wouldn't be suprised if i would run into the same issue. The problem is in being able to compensate for applying a new rotation and rotation-origin on an already transformed object. 

Handling zooming (on scroll) and panning (on drag) seems inconvenient to me.
Do you by any chance have a good example?